# Resolvconf does not add search domains to queries with dots

Tags: dns, resolve, consul, dnsmasq

## What I'm trying to do

I'm using Consul for dns, with dnsmasq acting as the proxy (https://www.consul.io/docs/guides/forwarding.html).

As well as querying consul directly (`nslookup my.service.consul`), I also want to be able to query without the `.consul` suffix (`nslookup my.service`).

## Environment

Ubuntu 16.04

### Config

#### /etc/resolv.conf

```
search consul
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

#### /etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
server=/consul/127.0.0.1#8600
server=8.8.8.8
server=8.8.4.4
```

#### /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 10.10.10.102
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  gateway 10.10.10.1
```

## The Problem

The problem I have is that queries for `my.service` do not have the `consul` search path appended by resolvconf.

If I change `/etc/resolv.conf` to:

```
search consul service.consul
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

and then search just for `my` (`nslookup my`), the `service.consul` suffix is correctly appended to the query succeeds with an address for `my.service.consul`.

But `consul` is *not* appended to `my.service` (`nslookup my.service`), even though the config is identical. Which makes me think that search domains are not appended to dotted queries.

## Things I've tried

I've tried `dns-search` in `/etc/network/interfaces`. No difference.

I've tried using dnsmasq's `resolv-file` option to specify a different file. Still no search suffixes added to dotted queries.

I've tried various options of the resolveconf ndots configuration options, but this doesn't work either. It correctly changes whether or not queries with insufficient dots are actually tried (as per the official resolvconf docs), but it never manages to convince resolvconf to add the `.consul` suffix to a dotted query: `my.service`.

(And a load of other combinations of those files and dnsmasq options that I tried before I even worked out that this was the problem... but which no longer seems relevant.)

## So my question ultimately is...

How do I persuade resolvconf to add the `consul` suffix for my dotted query `my.service` to get `my.service.consul`?

Please also bear in mind that I DO want the `service` to be manually specified in my queries and DO NOT want it as part of the dns search domain in resolv.conf. Particularly as consul has quite a dynamic dns search facility for datacenters etc and I'll quickly hit the 6 domain limit for the search entries in resolv.conf if I try to specify all the allowable combinations.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behaviour (on CentOS though),

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem? I am running into the same issue on RHEL 8 with /etc/resolv.conf and `dig` and `host` lookups. They are not doing additional lookups by appending the search domains if the entered argument has  a `.` in it.

Answer (score 0):

In resolv.conf: `options ndots:2`

Comment: I alluded to this in my original post. But to be clear; the ndots feature does NOT influence whether the search suffixes are added to the original query. It only influences whether an initial search is tried first; see http://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf.

Comment: And I tried that too, so not just talking theoretically. It didn't work.